# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of products of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a usual graded ring. Let $I$ , $J$ be monomial ideals.

**Definition:**
$reg(I)=\max\{j-i| \beta_{i,j}(I) \neq 0 \}$.

We know that $reg(I+J) \le reg(I)+reg(J)-1$.

Can we write $reg(IJ)$ in terms of $reg(I)$ and $reg(J)$ ?

Comment: It's well known that reg behaves badly on the product of ideals.